# AS3: Why is this fluid simulation running slower and slower?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, memory-management, fluid

I'v got 2 classes. Simulating fluid. Both classes are pretty straight forward and short, but after 2 seconds of running, the simulation gets really slow, looks like a memory leak. But i can't see any leaks in this code.

Please let me know if you can figure out, why this is happening?

FluidLayer.as

```
package  {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.display.IBitmapDrawable;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class FluidLayer extends MovieClip {

    private var canvas:Sprite;
    private var b:Bitmap;
    private var blur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(20,20,3);  
    private var bmd1:BitmapData;

    public function FluidLayer() {
        canvas = new Sprite();

        for(var i:int = 0;i < 600;i++){

            var p:Particle = new Particle();
            canvas.addChild(p);
            p.x = stage.stageWidth * Math.random();
            p.y = stage.stageHeight* Math.random();
            p.initi(stage);
        }

        canvas.filters = new Array(blur);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);


    }


    private function render(e:Event):void{

        remove();

        b = new Bitmap(makeFluid(canvas),"auto", true);
        b.alpha = 0.7;
        addChild(b);

    }

    private function makeFluid(o:Sprite):BitmapData{

        bmd1 = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true);
        bmd1.draw(o,null,null,null,null,true);
        bmd1.threshold(bmd1, bmd1.rect, new Point(0,0), ">", 0XFF2b2b2b, 0x55FFFF, 0xFFFFFF, false);

        return bmd1;
    }


    private function remove():void{
            if(numChildren > 1)
            removeChildAt(1);

            if(bmd1){ 
                bmd1.dispose();
                bmd1 = null;
            }
    }
```

}}

Particle.as

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;


public class Particle extends MovieClip {

    private var speedX:int;
    private var speedY:int;
    private var _s:Stage;       

    public function Particle() {
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x00CCFF);
        this.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,Math.random() * 30);

        speedX = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        speedY = Math.random() * 10 - 5;

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initi);

    }

    public function initi(s:Stage):void{
        this._s = s;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);
    }       

    private function render(e:Event):void{

        this.x += Math.random()*speedX;
        this.y += Math.random()*speedY;


        if(this.x > _s.stageWidth || this.y > _s.stageHeight){

            //this.x =  Math.random()*_s.stageWidth;
            //this.y =  Math.random()*_s.stageHeight;

            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i put together a solution for my question with the help of Andreas and adamh.

Andreas - showed me that i forgot to dispose the bitmapdata (really nice spot!)

Adamh - told me to define scrollrect on the canvas (Upped the performance a lot!)

But what did it in the end and made the performance fluid, was a simple mistake from my side. I noticed in the particle.as > render(), that i was only checking if the particle was out of bounds on 2 sides (facepalm), stupid mistake. When i changed the render function to check the remaining 2 sides, it fixed the performance issue.

Sorry for the stupid question :) and thanks again to Andreas and adamh

the final classes:

**FluidLayer.as**

```
package  {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.display.IBitmapDrawable;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;


public class FluidLayer extends MovieClip {

    private var canvas:Sprite;
    private var b:Bitmap;
    private var blur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(20,20,3);  
    private var bmd1:BitmapData;

    public function FluidLayer() {
        canvas = new Sprite();
        canvas.scrollRect = new Rectangle(0,0,1010,550);
        for(var i:int = 0;i < 600;i++){

            var p:Particle = new Particle();
            canvas.addChild(p);
            p.x = stage.stageWidth * Math.random();
            p.y = stage.stageHeight* Math.random();
            p.initi(stage);
        }

        canvas.filters = new Array(blur);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);


    }


    private function render(e:Event):void{

        remove();

        b = new Bitmap(makeFluid(canvas),"auto", true);
        b.alpha = 0.7;
        addChild(b);

    }

    private function makeFluid(o:Sprite):BitmapData{

        bmd1 = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true);
        bmd1.draw(o,null,null,null,null,true);
        bmd1.threshold(bmd1, bmd1.rect, new Point(0,0), ">", 0XFF2b2b2b, 0x55FFFF, 0xFFFFFF, false);

        return bmd1;
    }


    private function remove():void{
            if(numChildren > 1)
            removeChildAt(1);

            if(bmd1){ 

                bmd1.dispose();
                bmd1 = null;
            }
    }}}
```

**Particle.as**

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;


public class Particle extends MovieClip {

    private var speedX:int;
    private var speedY:int;
    private var _s:Stage;       

    public function Particle() {
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x00CCFF);
        this.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,Math.random() * 30);

        speedX = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        speedY = Math.random() * 10 - 5;

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initi);

    }

    public function initi(s:Stage):void{
        this._s = s;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);
    }       

    private function render(e:Event):void{

        this.x += Math.random()*speedX;
        this.y += Math.random()*speedY;


        if(this.x > _s.stageWidth || this.y > _s.stageHeight || this.x < 0 && this.y < 0){

            this.x =  Math.random()*_s.stageWidth;
            this.y =  Math.random()*_s.stageHeight;

            //removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);
            //this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call bmd1.dispose(); before reinstantiating it or it will not release the bitmap from memory.

**Edit:**

After looking through your code very carefully, optimizing it, and cleaning up some things, I have come to the conclusion that your simulation is no longer running slower and slower.

The problem was that the way you would calculate the particle's x and y speed. Essentially it would diminish in speed until stopping all together. On top of the massive high quality blur you have placed and the lack of freeing bitmaps, your movie would appear and actually slow to a crawl.

Here is your code I have modified. I benchmarked it and it didn't peak above 10% cpu or 40k memory after 15 minutes.

**Particle.as**

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;


public class Particle extends MovieClip {

    private var speedX:int;
    private var speedY:int;  
    private var deleted:Boolean = false;

    public function Particle() {
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x00CCFF);
        this.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,Math.random() * 30);

        //The max prevents particle speed from rounding to zero.
        speedX = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 - 5);
        speedY = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 - 5);
    }     

    public function render():void{
        //It originally appeared to be slowing down. In-fact, it was.
        x += Math.random() * speedX;
        y += Math.random() * speedY;

        deleted = (x > FluidLayer.w || y > FluidLayer.h);
        //Comment this below if you want particles to be removed once they go out of bounds.
        if(deleted) {
            x = Math.random() * FluidLayer.w;
            y = Math.random() * FluidLayer.h;
            deleted = false;
        }
    }

    public function isDeleted():Boolean {
        return deleted;
    }
}
}
```

**FluidLayer.as**

```
package  {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.display.IBitmapDrawable;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class FluidLayer extends MovieClip {

    private var canvas:Sprite;

    private var bitmap:Bitmap;
    private var bitmapData:BitmapData;

    private var particleArray:Array = new Array();

    public static const w:uint = 550;
    public static const h:uint = 400;


    public function FluidLayer() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
    }

    //By only one event handler to render, we prevent the overhead of 599 bubbling events.
    private function render(e:Event):void {
        for each(var p:Particle in particleArray) {
            p.render();
            //uncomment below if you want particles to become removed when they navigate out of bounds.
            //if(p.isDeleted()) {
                //canvas.removeChild(p);
                //particleArray.splice(particleArray.indexOf(p),1); 
            //}
        }
        bitmapData.fillRect(bitmapData.rect, 0); //clear the bitmapdata
        bitmapData.draw(canvas,null,null,null,null,true);
        bitmapData.threshold(bitmapData, bitmapData.rect, new Point(0,0), ">", 0XFF2b2b2b, 0x55FFFF, 0xFFFFFF, false);
    }


    //We call initialize once the fluid layer has been added to stage 
    //or else stage values will be null.
    private function initialize(e:Event):void {
        canvas = new Sprite();


        //You DEFINITELY want to lower the blur amount here.
        //This is what is ultimately slowing your SWF down to a crawl.
        //canvas.filters = new Array(new BlurFilter(20,20,1));

        for(var i:uint = 0; i < 600; i++) {
            var p:Particle = new Particle();
            p.x = Math.random() * w;
            p.y = Math.random() * h;
            canvas.addChild(p);
            particleArray.push(p);
        }

        //The bitmap and bitmapData only need to be initialized once
        bitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h, true);

        bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData, "auto", true);
        bitmap.alpha = 0.7;
        addChild(bitmap);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, really good point. It dosen't really solve my problem thou, still slowing down.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to do this Andreas! Definitely some nice ideas about the structure of the code. I figured out the solution to why it was slowing down, and it wasent the blur. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The original slowdown appears to be the blur filter on the canvas. (Comment the filter out to see proof)

The automatic creation of bitmaps by flash (CacheAsBitmap & Bitmap Filter buffers) to render the filter is likely causing the memory leak and this could be due the constantly changing dimension of canvas, due to the particles movement.

Try adding this line after creating canvas for a quick fix:

```
canvas.scrollRect = new Rectangle(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
```

By limiting the size of the canvas with the scrollRect we are stopping this reallocation.

However the fluid no longer goes to the edges of the stage. This could be worked around in the draw and bitmap allocation routines, increasing dimensions and offsetting, i'll let you have a go at that but its connected partially to the blur filter amount.

I'd suggest adapting these idea with the very good ideas in Andreas' code.

Comment: Thanks Adamh! this helped the performance a lot! see my answer. :)